# Z-Index of tiles/map from here.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, here-api

I am using the here.com Maps via their API as well as the Google Maps API.
I have a modal window which contains the map and I show with a button.

The Google Maps modal and the here.com modal have the exact same css:

```
.mapModal{
   height:calc(100% - 50px);
   width:calc(100% - 250px);
   top:52px;
   left:250px;
   padding:5px;
   position:fixed;
   display:none;
   border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
   z-index:3;
}
```

Now when I show the Google Maps one it looks like this:

[image]

But when I open the modal with here.com map it looks like this:

[image]

You can see the controls (top-left) and the here logo (bottom-left) and I can actually use the controls (zoom, change measurment etc.) 
Only the actual tiles don't show. They do get loaded though.
I assume it is a z-index problem, but how can I change that?

//EDIT created a pastebin with the created content inside the `.mapModal` div: http://pastebin.com/J1XRhCMr

I see two divs with z-index:0 (2nd and 3rd level) but changing it in the developer view of my browser also has no effect.

//EDIT2: Tracked down the problem to the following: The first initialization works if the div is visible. Then I can open and close it and it gets updated correctly. If upon initialization the containing div is hidden it won't render...

//EDIT3: I ended up with a 'dirty' workaround: on pageload show the mapcontainer div with 'loading data...', close after finished loading the page (here.com was also loaded), then it will display correctly for each click. Will accept the `map.getViewPort().resize()` though, as I have a strong feeling this is the right track! Thanks all

Comment: It sounds like they are being rendered prior to the rest of your page. [Can you create a fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Two issues with that: I have NO idea about jsfiddle and second, I cannot add the credentials, so it won't work anyway. I made one, but I can't even get the modal to show. Maybe it still gives a hint? https://jsfiddle.net/3rbgLh9b/1/

Comment: Is your browser javascript console spitting any errors out?

Comment: Not at all and if I render the same thing in a div that is visible from the very beginning (not hidden on load) it works like intended...

Comment: That'll work. Just need to get in and see the code.

Comment: Edited question, found the problem, no solution though (edit2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something interesting: In your pastebin extract I can see that the canvas has a size if 0x1 pixel. Looks to me like the map cannot measure the dimensions of the container properly when it is initialized. It also won't update the size automatically.

Can you check if calling map.getViewPort().[resize()](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-viewport.html#h-map-viewport__resize) after showing the map modal helps?